# Writing to textile

Tags: python

I have this amazing code that I would like to write the output to a textfile not quite sure how to write the data it gives me automatically into a text file?

```
import random
members = 5
participants=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
random.shuffle(participants)
for i in range(len(participants) // members + 1):
    print('Group {} consists of:'.format(i + 1))
    group = participants[i*members:i*members + members]
    for participant in group:
        print(participant)
```

Then also once its written how can I get it to read out the data out of the text file?

Thank you for any comments or answers!

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: not sure? I have no idea how to do this just asking for help :(

Comment: im not the one that downvoted you, but i imagine its because there are already many posts about "writing to a file in python". did you even try searching before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to a text file you must first open the text file, python makes this simple using open(filename, read or write)

```
import random
members = 5
participants=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
random.shuffle(participants)
with open("myfile.txt",'w') as tf:
    for i in range(len(participants) // members + 1):
        group = participants[i*members:i*members + members]
        for participant in group:
            tf.write("Group "+str(i+1)+" consists of:"+str(participant))
            tf.write("\n")
```

Would write each participant on a separate line.
To read those back:

```
with open("myfile.txt",'r') as tf:
    for line in tf.readlines():
        print(line)
```

To clarify, the following statements write to a file:

```
with open("myfile.txt",'w') as tf:
    tf.write("Some string of text")
```

tf is an object that allows you to operate upon the file

Comment: Thank you! How do I write it in the first place if you know?! Very helpful though!

Comment: @Olly what do you mean? It's there within the `with` block. If the file doesn't exist it automatically creates one for you

Comment: Sorry, I mean it like gives me input but doesn't put it into a textile, so I run the function and it just gives me the groups/number etc however how could i get it to write the data onto a text file for me?

Comment: try running the first block of code, they'll be a new text file in the same directory as the python code containing data written

Comment: @riscnotcisc and @mangoHero! Thank you sooo much guys! been such on this for agers! Super appreciated :)

Comment: One last question, Is it possible to write to excel aswell with the group number in one collumn and the number in the next one? Sorry to bother you guys again!

Comment: Yes, look at python's csv module. Or just open a file called "myfile.csv" then between columns write a comma and between rows write a newline ("\n")